# How to set up a websites folder so the Url address outputs as a index of directory

Tags: wordpress

Its a WordPress website using a nginx webservers, we created a folder using FTPS to download/upload files into the new directory, and want the output folder to show like the example link below. Anyone would like to help me out thanks a ton!
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCaiD.png]

Comment: Your question is too broad my friend.

Comment: Sorry, We currently have a wordpress website that we manage multiple dealer accounts on. We are trying to create a page with different folders assigned to each dealer accessible to all the dealers and the output needs to be from a index of directory like the example i posted above.  We will use the wordpress CP to upload/download all the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Directory Listing in NGINX

To enable directory listing, it's as simple as adding this:

```
autoindex on;
```

To either a site's NGINX config file (e.g. /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com), or in your `http` NGINX block for it to always occur on all your sites. Here's an example site config from [this article](http://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/):

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
    access_log  /var/...........................;
    root   /path/to/root;
    // autoindex on; // put it here for site wide listings
   
    location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /somedir { // Or use location to target particular dirs
           autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Comment: @sinewaves No problem :) If it answers your question please don't forget to upvote/ accept/ both so others know it's been answered.

Comment: Most defiantly I'm working on the site now so once i get it solved I will update the page.

Comment: didn't work. I tried adding it both to nginx.conf, mywebsite.com sites-available and nginx outputs errors when i restart nginx, I built the stack using easy engine may wonder over to the rt community and reach out see what i can come up with. ty

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed:** Only had add `autoindex on;` to the `mywebsite.com.conf` file.

```
root /var/www/mywebsite.com/htdocs/;
autoindex on;
```

Thanks Luke!